# Passing dynamic TemplateRef in NzMessageService - Angular 15

Tags: html, angular, templates, angular-components, ng-zorro-antd

I'm working on an Angular application where I'm using NzMessageService from Ng-Zorro Ant Design to display messages. I'm trying to pass a dynamic TemplateRef to the NzMessageService but facing some challenges.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
import { Injectable, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NzMessageService } from 'ng-zorro-antd/message';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DynamicMessageService {
  constructor(private messageService: NzMessageService) {}

  showMessage(dynamicText: string | TemplateRef<void>): void {
    // I'm trying to create a dynamic component or view and pass it to NzMessageService
    
    this.messageService.create('error', /* ??? */, { nzDuration: 80000 });
  }
}
```

The dynamicText can be either a string or a TemplateRef. I've tried creating a dynamic component or view, but I'm encountering issues with type mismatches.

Can someone provide guidance on the best approach to achieve this in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

If you just want to configure the templates, create a separate component, that will contain the templates, if you want different templates, just create more template reference and separate methods to open the messages.

messages container to contain all the templates

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NzMessageDataOptions, NzMessageService } from 'ng-zorro-antd/message';
import { MessageService } from '../message-service.service';
import { CustomComponentShowInsideMessageComponent } from './custom-component-show-inside-message/custom-component-show-inside-message.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-message',
  template: `
  <ng-template #template>
    <app-custom-component-show-inside-message/>
  </ng-template>
  `,
  imports: [CustomComponentShowInsideMessageComponent],
  standalone: true,
})
export class CustomMessageComponent {
  @ViewChild('template') template!: TemplateRef<void>;

  constructor(private message: MessageService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    debugger;
    this.message.template = this.template;
  }
}
```

message service

```
import { Injectable, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NzMessageDataOptions, NzMessageService } from 'ng-zorro-antd/message';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  template!: TemplateRef<void>;

  constructor(private message: NzMessageService) {}

  open(
    type: 'success' | 'info' | 'warning' | 'error' | 'loading' | string,
    customTemplate: TemplateRef<void> = null,
    options: NzMessageDataOptions = null
  ): void {
    this.message.create(type, customTemplate || this.template, options);
  }
}
```

app component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MessageService } from './message-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-message-info',
  template: ` 
  <button nz-button [nzType]="'primary'" (click)="createBasicMessage()">Display normal message</button> 
  <app-custom-message/>
  `,
})
export class NzDemoMessageInfoComponent {
  constructor(private message: MessageService) {}

  createBasicMessage() {
    this.message.open('error', null, { nzDuration: 80000 });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-da8dch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I do not want to create a component to use component selector,
 when my api was failed i want to create custom TemplateRef for each error message and then inject this TemplateRef to NzMessageService

Comment: @abolfazl_mehdi I am injecting a template inside the message service, do you mean you want to configure it only once? We have to pass the template in each time you open the message

Comment: you have created a TempleteRef inside app.component 

i want to have a espesefic component for TempleteRef and and button for show message be in another component and by clicking on button inject the templeteRef Component into nzService by getting help from middlware service

Comment: Thank you very much, with a little change of your code it solved my problem